# flash android apps without installing adobe air

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

i am a newbie in flash programming. i got a issue with adobe air. As i have done all the things with Air for android. I tested with air in android sdk emulator. everything's working fine but the thing is How to run flash android apps without installing adobe air? Are there any tools or converters available for this. If any please suggest me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Captive Runtime on Android since AIR 3.0 won't need to have AIR installed as the runtime will be bundled within the app.

If you're using Flash Builder, go through [Captive Runtime packaging in Air 3.0.](http://houseofbilz.com/archives/2011/10/11/captive-runtime-packaging-in-air-3-0/)

If not, follow this : [Installation and deployment options in Adobe AIR 3](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air3-install-and-deployment-options.html)

But if you want to use Flex or Flash, you need Air. Otherwise 
you can use another cross-platform tool, like Phonegap.

Or if you want small, lean apps, with maximum device compatibility, nothing compares with using Java and the stock Android SDK.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Flash Professional then go to the steps

1. go to in publish settings tab and click on Target settings icon
2. put your general information and go to the Deployment Tab
3. choose your certificate and fill password then
4. select radio button of Device release
5. next is select radio button of Embed AIR runtime with application
6. if your Device is connected then click the check box of Install application on the connected Android Device.

then Publish It.

**Note:** this steps is showing in Flash Professional cs5, cs5.5 and cs6 maybe because i am using cs6 so check it first

Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

You can use the captive runtime option, which packs air into the native application package. Other than that, you don't have any other option to deploy your app other than converting it to native Java code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using FlashDevelop, there's a file called PackageApp.bat in your main app directory. Just run it, and there you can choose to build normal, debug and captive runtime, for android and ios.